# How to change panel width when panel's width is already binded to a Storyboard

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have applied a storyboard animation at design time to change a stackpanel width. But when I explicitly change same control's width on a button click, then there is no change in its width.
When I do not apply any storyBoard at design time, then width change works.

Is there any way to remove storyboard binding from a panel control and apply same whenever I want on a button click.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DependencyProperty`s react to change requests from different sources with different precedences. You can find out more in the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#animations) article on MSDN. In your situation, the change requests to the `StackPanel.Width` `DependencyProperty` sent from the `Animation` object override any changes made in a `Trigger` `Setter` object.

The easiest thing to do is to pause or stop the `Storyboard` in the `Button.Click` handler before you change the `StackPanel.Width`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306163/how-can-i-pause-a-storyboard) which deals with a similar situation. You can find further information in the MSDN [Storyboard.Pause Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605764.aspx) article.