# SetTarget vs RegisterName/SetTargetName

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

Here's a simple program which animates the `Y2` property of a `Line` shape. Note that I use the `SetTarget` method to target the `Line`. This program works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SoGeneratingAnimatedLine
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            Content = canvas;

            var sb = new Storyboard();

            var line = new Line()
            {
                X1 = 10, Y1 = 10,
                X2 = 90, Y2 = 10,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 2
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(line);

            var animation = new DoubleAnimation(10, 90, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));

            sb.Children.Add(animation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, line);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Line.Y2Property));

            MouseDown += (s, e) => sb.Begin(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a similar program which animates the `EndPoint` of a `LineGeometry` which is the `Data` for a `Path`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SoGeneratingAnimatedLine
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var canvas = new Canvas();

            Content = canvas;

            var sb = new Storyboard();

            var lineGeometry = 
                new LineGeometry(new Point(10, 10), new Point(90, 10));

            var path = new Path()
            {
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 2,
                Data = lineGeometry
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(path);

            var animation =
                new PointAnimation(
                    new Point(90, 10),
                    new Point(90, 90),
                    new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));

            sb.Children.Add(animation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, lineGeometry);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(LineGeometry.EndPointProperty));

            MouseDown += (s, e) => sb.Begin(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This second version does *not* work. However, if I replace the line:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, lineGeometry);
```

with:

```
RegisterName("geometry", lineGeometry);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "geometry");
```

then the animation runs.

Why doesn't the `SetTarget` version of the second program work? When is it OK to use `SetTarget` instead of the `RegisterName`/`SetTargetName` combo? What's the difference in the two approaches?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need at all for a Storyboard. Just call [BeginAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590761.aspx) directly on the LineGeometry:

```
lineGeometry.BeginAnimation(LineGeometry.EndPointProperty, animation);
```

Comment: Hi Clemens. It's true that a `Storyboard` is going overboard for this case, however, I wanted to pick an example that was simple for purposes of illustration.

Comment: My three questions at the end still apply. :-)

Comment: You're right. Maybe the *Remarks* section in [RegisterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername.aspx) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Calling RegisterName is necessary in order to correctly hook up animation storyboards for applications when created in code. This is because one of the key storyboard properties, [TargetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname?view=netframework-4.8), uses a run-time name lookup instead of being able to take a reference to a target element. This is true even if that element is accessible by reference from the code.