# WPF RotateTransform not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I found below code to let my image(indicator1) rotation.

But it's nothing happened when I click the button.

Anyone know how to solve it?

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RotateTransform rotateTransform = indicator1.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = 0;
        doubleAnimation.To = 360;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, rotateTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(RotateTransform.AngleProperty));

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it's not working" a picture or description or error messages are necessary for someone to aid you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Storyboard`. Using a `Storyboard` from code behind [requires a workaround to get the target name lookup to to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662734/424129). I haven't researched the exact cause of this, or whether or not it's always an issue. The code below works.

Note that you'll be setting `RepeatBehavior` on the `DoubleAnimation` now.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform rotateTransform = indicator1.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = 0;
    doubleAnimation.To = 360;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));

    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

    rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I need a storyboard because I have serial  animation after that.

Comment: @jim Then see the linked answer which shows a workaround for a storyboard.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!